# Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, jhipster

after checking out a java maven project, my pom has some errors all the time. maven clean and maven install work like a charm, but maven update project or download sources/java doc give me everytime the following error:

```
Could not download sources or javadoc
Could not read maven project
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:pom:3.0.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out @ line 106, column 16
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:jar is missing. @ line 118, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar is missing. @ line 123, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar is missing. @ line 127, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc:jar is missing. @ line 131, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar is missing. @ line 135, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar is missing. @ line 139, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.h2database:h2:jar is missing. @ line 867, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar is missing. @ line 148, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar is missing. @ line 154, column 15
```

Im behind a corporate proxy, which i already configured in eclipse.

I had never anything to do with maven in my past, only checking worked for me every time.
The project is set up with jHipster.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks `connect timed out..` like a network/firewall/proxy issue..

Comment: Try to put maven in verbose to see more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who wants to know how I resolved this issue:

First of all like khmarbaise already mentioned, it was a proxy issue. It was already configured in eclipse, therefore I assumned that maven will automatically use the already set proxy configurations from eclipse.

The solution was to create/modify the settings.xml and set it via following eclipse configuration steps:

Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings, and there configure the path to the settings.xml at the User Settings Input.

I edited my settings.xml and configured my company proxy in it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the fantastic solution of this problem, let's go to your project ,right click on project the go to maven update tab and the forcefully update your project , it takes some time and then your project works perfectly fine

Comment: Please use civil language here, thx.

Comment: Already tried that in my occasion and it saldy didn't work - as my proxy was the original problem here.

Comment: force updating maven worked for me so this is the solution IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Just click on update maven and it works fine.
Steps:
Restart STS/Eclipse->Right click on project->Click on Maven->Click on Update Maven

Comment: the question is already answerd nearly two years ago - and if you would have read the second sentence - you would have known, that maven update didnt work in that occasion